# how do I save my buffer in vi without exiting?

Tags: console, vi

how do I save my buffer in vi without exiting?

.

Comment: -1? I did google, I did RTFM x_x

Comment: the first result for [vi save](https://www.google.com/search?q=vi+save) has the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `:w` and your file will be saved.